# N2D/C2 quota for europe

Tags: google-compute-engine, quota

I am a google cloud user which created a **cloud HPC** system. The web application is *really consuming* in terms of hardware resources [it's quite common that I have 4/5 N1 instances allocated with 96 cores each for a total of more than 400 cores].

I found that currently in certain zones it's **possible to use N2D and C2 instances** which are higher in terms of CPU the first ones and dedicated to the computing the latter. Unluckily I can't use these two instances because, for some reason, I have ***troubles increasing the quota N2D_CPUS and C2_CPUS*** above the default value of 24 [which is nothing considering my needs].

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to increase the quota is to submit a [Quota Increase request](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota). Once you submit the request, you should receive an email saying that the request has been submitted and that it is being reviewed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. My problem is that by following that procedure I get my request rejected at all times. I tried to contact technical support and they redirect me to the commercial one. I tried then to contact the commercial support, and they redirect me to the technical support. I am a bit confused on how I can proceed!

Comment: If the quota team rejects the request, then there is not much more you can do. The only other option is to get GCP Support and maybe then they can help you.